# How to escape HTML-entity inside Rails helper function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, html-escape-characters

In my Rails application I have a helper function like this:

```
def format_datetime(time)
  datetime = [current_user.date_format, current_user.time_format].join(" &mdash; ")
  time.strftime(datetime)
end
```

The problem is it returns the m-dash as an HTML-entity:

```
# => 14.12.2012 &mdash; 10:53AM
```

How can this be fixed?

I tried `.html_safe` in some places but to no avail.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

```
def format_datetime(time)
  datetime = [current_user.date_format, current_user.time_format].join(" &mdash; ")
  time.strftime(datetime).html_safe
end
```

works for me

Comment: OK, I fixed this by simply using a comma instead of an `m-dash`. Not really a solution but it works for the moment. Thanks for taking the time and helping me.

Comment: If you're introducing another string when you use it in the view - such as "time: #{ format_datetime(Time.now) }" then you'll need to html_safe that string also.

Answer (score -1):

Try  this:

```
def format_datetime(time)
  datetime = [current_user.date_format, current_user.time_format].join(" &mdash; ")
  time.strftime(datetime).gsub('&mdash;', '-')
end
```

Comment: I fixed this, try now.

Comment: Not working. The `mdash` gets replaced here with a normal `dash` which is not what I want. Thanks for your help though!